# 400 Bad Request for too long request parameter in PUT request

Tags: java, spring-mvc, sap-commerce-cloud, restful-authentication

I'm trying to hit a PUT api through URL

https://localhost:9002/serialNumbers/700027601?consignmentCode=700027601_c0&productSku=120398ID&serialNumbers=1@120398ID@000N@12345,@120398ID@000N@12346,@120398ID@000N@12347,@120398ID@000N@12348,@120398ID@000N@12349,@120398ID@000N@12350,@120398ID@000N@12351,@120398ID@000N@12352,@120398ID@000N@12353,@120398ID@000N@12354,@120398ID@000N@12355,@120398ID@000N@12356,@120398ID@000N@12357,@120398ID@000N@12358,@120398ID@000N@12359,@120398ID@000N@12360,@120398ID@000N@12361,@120398ID@000N@12362,@120398ID@000N@12363,@120398ID@000N@12364,@120398ID@000N@12365,@120398ID@000N@12366,@120398ID@000N@12367,@120398ID@000N@12368,@120398ID@000N@12369,@120398ID@000N@12370,@120398ID@000N@12371,@120398ID@000N@12372,@120398ID@000N@12373,@120398ID@000N@12374,@120398ID@000N@12375,@120398ID@000N@12376,@120398ID@000N@12377,@120398ID@000N@12378,@120398ID@000N@12379,@120398ID@000N@12380,@120398ID@000N@12381,@120398ID@000N@12382,@120398ID@000N@12383,@120398ID@000N@12384,@120398ID@000N@12385,@120398ID@000N@12386,@120398ID@000N@12387,@120398ID@000N@12388,@120398ID@000N@12389,@120398ID@000N@12390,@120398ID@000N@12391,@120398ID@000N@12392,@120398ID@000N@12393,@120398ID@000N@12394,@120398ID@000N@12395,@120398ID@000N@12396,@120398ID@000N@12397,@120398ID@000N@12398,@120398ID@000N@12399,@120398ID@000N@12400,@120398ID@000N@12401,@120398ID@000N@12402,@120398ID@000N@12403,@120398ID@000N@12404,@120398ID@000N@12405,@120398ID@000N@12406,@120398ID@000N@12407,@120398ID@000N@12408,@120398ID@000N@12409,@120398ID@000N@12410,@120398ID@000N@12411,@120398ID@000N@12412,@120398ID@000N@12413,@120398ID@000N@12414,@120398ID@000N@12415,@120398ID@000N@12416,@120398ID@000N@12417,@120398ID@000N@12418,@120398ID@000N@12419,@120398ID@000N@12420,@120398ID@000N@12421,@120398ID@000N@12422,@120398ID@000N@12423,@120398ID@000N@12424,@120398ID@000N@12425,@120398ID@000N@12426,@120398ID@000N@12427,@120398ID@000N@12428,@120398ID@000N@12429,@120398ID@000N@12430,@120398ID@000N@12431,@120398ID@000N@12432,@120398ID@000N@12433,@120398ID@000N@12434,@120398ID@000N@12435,@120398ID@000N@12436,@120398ID@000N@12437,@120398ID@000N@12438,@120398ID@000N@12439,@120398ID@000N@12440,@120398ID@000N@12441,@120398ID@000N@12442,@120398ID@000N@12443,@120398ID@000N@12444,@120398ID@000N@12445,@120398ID@000N@12446,@120398ID@000N@12447,@120398ID@000N@12448,@120398ID@000N@12449,@120398ID@000N@12450,@120398ID@000N@12451,@120398ID@000N@12452,@120398ID@000N@12453,@120398ID@000N@12454,@120398ID@000N@12455,@120398ID@000N@12456,@120398ID@000N@12457,@120398ID@000N@12458,@120398ID@000N@12459,@120398ID@000N@12460,@120398ID@000N@12461,@120398ID@000N@12462,@120398ID@000N@12463,@120398ID@000N@12464,@120398ID@000N@12465,@120398ID@000N@12466,@120398ID@000N@12467,@120398ID@000N@12468,@120398ID@000N@12469,@120398ID@000N@12470,@120398ID@000N@12471,@120398ID@000N@12472,@120398ID@000N@12473,@120398ID@000N@12474,@120398ID@000N@12475,@120398ID@000N@12476,@120398ID@000N@12477,@120398ID@000N@12478,@120398ID@000N@12479,@120398ID@000N@12480,@120398ID@000N@12481,@120398ID@000N@12482,@120398ID@000N@12483,@120398ID@000N@12484,@120398ID@000N@12485,@120398ID@000N@12486,@120398ID@000N@12487,@120398ID@000N@12488,@120398ID@000N@12489,@120398ID@000N@12490,@120398ID@000N@12491,@120398ID@000N@12492,@120398ID@000N@12493,@120398ID@000N@12494,@120398ID@000N@12495,@120398ID@000N@12496,@120398ID@000N@12497,@120398ID@000N@12498,@120398ID@000N@12499,@120398ID@000N@12500,@120398ID@000N@12501,@120398ID@000N@12502,@120398ID@000N@12503,@120398ID@000N@12504,@120398ID@000N@12505,@120398ID@000N@12506,@120398ID@000N@12507,@120398ID@000N@12508,@120398ID@000N@12509,@120398ID@000N@12510,@120398ID@000N@12511,@120398ID@000N@12512,@120398ID@000N@12513,@120398ID@000N@12514,@120398ID@000N@12515,@120398ID@000N@12516,@120398ID@000N@12517,@120398ID@000N@12518,@120398ID@000N@12519,@120398ID@000N@12520,@120398ID@000N@12521,@120398ID@000N@12522,@120398ID@000N@12523,@120398ID@000N@12524,@120398ID@000N@12525,@120398ID@000N@12526,@120398ID@000N@12527,@120398ID@000N@12528,@120398ID@000N@12529,@120398ID@000N@12530,@120398ID@000N@12531,@120398ID@000N@12532,@120398ID@000N@12533,@120398ID@000N@12534,@120398ID@000N@12535,@120398ID@000N@12536,@120398ID@000N@12537,@120398ID@000N@12538,@120398ID@000N@12539,@120398ID@000N@12540,@120398ID@000N@12541,@120398ID@000N@12542,@120398ID@000N@12543,@120398ID@000N@12544,@120398ID@000N@12545,@120398ID@000N@12546,@120398ID@000N@12547,@120398ID@000N@12548,@120398ID@000N@12549,@120398ID@000N@12550,@120398ID@000N@12551,@120398ID@000N@12552,@120398ID@000N@12553,@120398ID@000N@12554,@120398ID@000N@12555,@120398ID@000N@12556,@120398ID@000N@12557,@120398ID@000N@12558,@120398ID@000N@12559,@120398ID@000N@12560,@120398ID@000N@12561,@120398ID@000N@12562,@120398ID@000N@12563,@120398ID@000N@12564,@120398ID@000N@12565,@120398ID@000N@12566,@120398ID@000N@12567,@120398ID@000N@12568,@120398ID@000N@12569,@120398ID@000N@12570,@120398ID@000N@12571,@120398ID@000N@12572,@120398ID@000N@12573,@120398ID@000N@12574,@120398ID@000N@12575,@120398ID@000N@12576,@120398ID@000N@12577,@120398ID@000N@12578,@120398ID@000N@12579,@120398ID@000N@12580,@120398ID@000N@12581,@120398ID@000N@12582,@120398ID@000N@12583,@120398ID@000N@12584,@120398ID@000N@12585,@120398ID@000N@12586,@120398ID@000N@12587,@120398ID@000N@12588,@120398ID@000N@12589,@120398ID@000N@12590,@120398ID@000N@12591,@120398ID@000N@12592,@120398ID@000N@12593,@120398ID@000N@12594,@120398ID@000N@12595,@120398ID@000N@12596,@120398ID@000N@12597,@120398ID@000N@12598,@120398ID@000N@12599,@120398ID@000N@12600,@120398ID@000N@12601,@120398ID@000N@12602,@120398ID@000N@12603,@120398ID@000N@12604,@120398ID@000N@12605,@120398ID@000N@12606,@120398ID@000N@12607,@120398ID@000N@12608,@120398ID@000N@12609,@120398ID@000N@12610,@120398ID@000N@12611,@120398ID@000N@12612,@120398ID@000N@12613,@120398ID@000N@12614,@120398ID@000N@12615,@120398ID@000N@12616,@120398ID@000N@12617,@120398ID@000N@12618,@120398ID@000N@12619,@120398ID@000N@12620,@120398ID@000N@12621,@120398ID@000N@12622,@120398ID@000N@12623,@120398ID@000N@12624,@120398ID@000N@12625,@120398ID@000N@12626,@120398ID@000N@12627,@120398ID@000N@12628,@120398ID@000N@12629,@120398ID@000N@12630,@120398ID@000N@12631,@120398ID@000N@12632,@120398ID@000N@12633,@120398ID@000N@12634,@120398ID@000N@12635,@120398ID@000N@12636,@120398ID@000N@12637,@120398ID@000N@12638,@120398ID@000N@12639,@120398ID@000N@12640,@120398ID@000N@12641,@120398ID@000N@12642,@120398ID@000N@12643,@120398ID@000N@12644,@120398ID@000N@12645,@120398ID@000N@12646,@120398ID@000N@12647,@120398ID@000N@12648,@120398ID@000N@12649,@120398ID@000N@12650,@120398ID@000N@12651,@120398ID@000N@12652,@120398ID@000N@12653,@120398ID@000N@12654,@120398ID@000N@12655,@120398ID@000N@12656,@120398ID@000N@12657,@120398ID@000N@12658,@120398ID@000N@12659,@120398ID@000N@12660,@120398ID@000N@12661,@120398ID@000N@12662,@120398ID@000N@12663,@120398ID@000N@12664,@120398ID@000N@12665,@120398ID@000N@12666,@120398ID@000N@12667,@120398ID@000N@12668,@120398ID@000N@12669,@120398ID@000N@12670,@120398ID@000N@12671,@120398ID@000N@12672,@120398ID@000N@12673,@120398ID@000N@12674,@120398ID@000N@12675,@120398ID@000N@12676,@120398ID@000N@12677,@120398ID@000N@12678,@120398ID@000N@12679&serialType=SSL&freeItem=false

It is showing 400 bad request errors when trying to hit in the higher environments. When I'm decreasing the length it is working fine.
Can anyone help me how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Such as you write, it's too long for the URL. You can fix it with multiple way :

1. Include this long char in the body, such as with `POST` request. This will enable you to make request with a lot of char.
2. Convert all char into a base64 string that can be lower in size with somethiing like this:

```
Base64.encode(myStr);
```

3. Change the string format by, for example, changing all `@000N` into `@O` (to replace 5 char to 2), and change like `@120398ID@000N,@120398ID@000N` to `2x@120398ID@000N`